# iOS 13 Crash - Backtrace not available

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios13

Dealing with a confounding crash for an iOS app. The application worked fine in previous iOS versions, but in iOS 13 it crashes before getting past the launch screen. This doesn't happen on the simulator or running on a device from Xcode, but *does* happen on the released version and when an archive build is deployed via fabric-beta.

When pulling a log from a device, all I get is (after the app info):

```
Date/Time:           2019-10-01 11:34:58.1246 -0500
Launch Time:         2019-10-01 11:34:57.8849 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.1.1 (17A854)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    1.01.17
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Assertion failed: ((_containerTypedBytes->payloadLength + sizeof(TypedBytes) + payloadSize) < (16 * 1024 * 1024)), function append, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/dyld/dyld-732.3/dyld3/ClosureWriter.cpp, line 84.
Highlighted by Thread:  0

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000006   x1: 0x0000000000000009   x2: 0x000000016bac4b00   x3: 0x0000000000000014
    x4: 0x000000016bac4700   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000002   x7: 0x0000000015f4f170
    x8: 0x0000000000000020   x9: 0x0000000000000009  x10: 0x7257657275736f6c  x11: 0x7070632e72657469
   x12: 0x75736f6c432f3364  x13: 0x7265746972576572  x14: 0x696c202c7070632e  x15: 0x000a2e343820656e
   x16: 0x0000000000000209  x17: 0x00000001225417f4  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x000000016bac4700  x21: 0x0000000000000014  x22: 0x000000016bac4b00  x23: 0x0000000000000009
   x24: 0x0000000000000006  x25: 0x00000001225e1b28  x26: 0x0000000122568194  x27: 0x000000000000ba00
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016bac46d0   lr: 0x000000012254e74c
    sp: 0x000000016bac4690   pc: 0x000000012254717c cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x00000000  Address size fault

Binary images description not available

Error Formulating Crash Report:
Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

EOF
```

It's pretty devoid of information, but it appears to be a crash in Apple's [`ClosureWriter.cpp`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-635.2/dyld3/ClosureWriter.cpp.auto.html) but there's no indication of how or where this is happening.

Is this Apple's bug? Is it a problem with a library? Is there a workaround? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm seeing this exact same backtrace on tvOS... and I'd really, really like to know how to fix it :)

Comment: The only way I was able to get it to run is taking out a part of the app that was taking up a very large amount of disk space. Hopefully will have a more concrete answer at some point 

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Probably it seems you're deallocating some variables earlier.

Best Regards